# Android:What does `NoActionBar` do in theme?

Tags: android

I have seen a lot of theme named with "NoActionBar". What does this mean exactly? I can't find any useful information after googling a lot.

By the way, does "NoActionBar" mean "NoToolBar" too?

Answer (score 2):

It is what it says, the theme with no action bar. For further info, see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

Answer (score 2):

It removes the ActionBar/Toolbar.

If you look up the source of appcompat-v7 library you will notice:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

So basically if you inherit from it you don't have to set them by your own.